# Pyrogram KeyError: 6972409882

Tags: python, linux, telegram, pyrogram

есть рабочий клиент по пирограмме. Забирает данные из отправленных ботом сообщений. Работает стабильно, но по какой-то причине выскочила ошибка в стандартных условиях работы.
Вот код ошибки:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):                                             │
│││ bot >   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pyrogram/dispatcher.py",       │
│││ bot >     await parser(update, users, chats)                                         │
│││ bot >   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pyrogram/dispatcher.py",       │
│││ bot >     await pyrogram.types.Message._parse(self.client, update.message, users,    │
│││ bot >   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pyrogram/types/messages_and_m  │
│││ bot >     sender_chat = types.Chat._parse(client, message, users, chats, is_chat=Fa  │
│││ bot >   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pyrogram/types/user_and_chats  │
│││ bot >     return Chat._parse_chat_chat(client, chats[chat_id])                       │
│││ bot > KeyError: 6972409882
```

На сколько я понимаю это ошибка чисто в pyrogram. Может быть ктото сталкивался? Буду рад любой информации, гугл не находит ничего похожего в принципе..

Ошибка возникла в момент получения текста из сообщения, раньше такого не случалось и пока не повторилось.

Ниже прикладываю код:

```
import sys

from pyrogram import Client, filters, errors
from pyrogram.types import Message

from parser import parse_message


[name] = sys.argv[1:]

chanel_id = -4004502393
bot_id = 6972409882 

session_errors = (errors.ActiveUserRequired, errors.AuthKeyInvalid, errors.AuthKeyPermEmpty, errors.AuthKeyUnregistered,
                errors.AuthKeyDuplicated, errors.SessionExpired, errors.SessionPasswordNeeded, errors.SessionRevoked,
                errors.UserDeactivated, errors.UserDeactivatedBan, AttributeError)

try:
    app = Client(name)
    app.start()
    app.get_me()
    app.stop()

    @app.on_message(filters.chat(chanel_id) & filters.user(bot_id) & ~filters.outgoing)
    async def watch_chanel(client: Client, message: Message):
        try:
            client_telegram = str(client.me.id)

            print("Test point")
            data = parse_message(message.text)
            print(data)

            # some logic...

        except Exception as err:
            print(err)


    app.run()
except session_errors:
    print(session_errors)
    print("wrong session")
except Exception as err:
    print(err)
```

Ошибка происходит в функции watch_chanel и еще до вывода в консоль

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой (**«почему этот код не работает?»**) должны включать желаемое поведение, *конкретную проблему или ошибку* и *минимальный код* для её воспроизведения **прямо в вопросе**.